# Form that does not persist data Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, many-to-one, symfony5

Hello,
I am unable to make my form data persist. It only works on one side.

The 'Target' form allows you to create targets and link them to activities : it's OK.

In my 'Activities' form I also have a 'Target' field which displays the targets that are related, but I can't seem to modify them. My choice persists only on the 'Target' form side.

I only want to be able to select some on the activity page, nothing more.

**TargetType.php :**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Target;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TargetType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('activity')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Target::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**ActivityType.php :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Activity;
use App\Entity\Target;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ActivityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('targets', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Target::class,
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
            ])
            ->add('types')
            ->add('packs')
            ->add('partners')
            ->add('places')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Activity::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Target Entity :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\TargetRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TargetRepository::class)
 */
class Target
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Activity::class, inversedBy="targets", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $activity;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->activity = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Activity[]
     */
    public function getActivity(): Collection
    {
        return $this->activity;
    }

    public function addActivity(Activity $activity): self
    {
        if (!$this->activity->contains($activity)) {
            $this->activity[] = $activity;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeActivity(Activity $activity): self
    {
        if ($this->activity->contains($activity)) {
            $this->activity->removeElement($activity);
        }

        return $this;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return
            $this->name;
    }
}
```

**Activity Entity :**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ActivityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ActivityRepository::class)
 */
class Activity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Target::class, mappedBy="activity",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $targets;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Type::class, mappedBy="activity")
     */
    private $types;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Pack::class, mappedBy="activity")
     */
    private $packs;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Partner::class, mappedBy="activity")
     */
    private $partners;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Place::class, mappedBy="activity")
     */
    private $places;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Gallery::class, mappedBy="activity")
     */
    private $image;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->targets = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->types = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->packs = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->partners = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->places = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->image = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Target[]
     */
    public function getTargets(): Collection
    {
        return $this->targets;
    }

    public function addTarget(Target $target): self
    {
        if (!$this->targets->contains($target)) {
            $this->targets[] = $target;
            $target->addActivity($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeTarget(Target $target): self
    {
        if ($this->targets->contains($target)) {
            $this->targets->removeElement($target);
            $target->removeActivity($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Type[]
     */
    public function getTypes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->types;
    }

    public function addType(Type $type): self
    {
        if (!$this->types->contains($type)) {
            $this->types[] = $type;
            $type->addActivity($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeType(Type $type): self
    {
        if ($this->types->contains($type)) {
            $this->types->removeElement($type);
            $type->removeActivity($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Pack[]
     */
    public function getPacks(): Collection
    {
        return $this->packs;
    }

    public function addPack(Pack $pack): self
    {
        if (!$this->packs->contains($pack)) {
            $this->packs[] = $pack;
            $pack->addActivity($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePack(Pack $pack): self
    {
        if ($this->packs->contains($pack)) {
            $this->packs->removeElement($pack);
            $pack->removeActivity($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Partner[]
     */
    public function getPartners(): Collection
    {
        return $this->partners;
    }

    public function addPartner(Partner $partner): self
    {
        if (!$this->partners->contains($partner)) {
            $this->partners[] = $partner;
            $partner->addActivity($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePartner(Partner $partner): self
    {
        if ($this->partners->contains($partner)) {
            $this->partners->removeElement($partner);
            $partner->removeActivity($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Place[]
     */
    public function getPlaces(): Collection
    {
        return $this->places;
    }

    public function addPlace(Place $place): self
    {
        if (!$this->places->contains($place)) {
            $this->places[] = $place;
            $place->addActivity($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePlace(Place $place): self
    {
        if ($this->places->contains($place)) {
            $this->places->removeElement($place);
            $place->removeActivity($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Gallery[]
     */
    public function getImage(): Collection
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function addImage(Gallery $image): self
    {
        if (!$this->image->contains($image)) {
            $this->image[] = $image;
            $image->setActivity($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeImage(Gallery $image): self
    {
        if ($this->image->contains($image)) {
            $this->image->removeElement($image);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($image->getActivity() === $this) {
                $image->setActivity(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {

        return
            $this->name;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force the call of the setter of the `Target` in your `ActivityType` by setting the `by_reference` property to `false` :

```
class ActivityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('targets', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Target::class,
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'by_reference' => false // <- done in this line here
            ])
    // ...
```

More info in the docs here :
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference